# Lift assigned to specific agent type Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, lift

I've a question, in my model I've multiple lift areas with 2 lifts, but only 1 lift is assigned for good transport (so agent type=AGV ) may use this lifts and the other lift is assigned for persons (agent type= person).

Is there a way to make the agents know which lift they should take and not take the lift which is not assigned for this specific goods transport.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
agent instanceof AGV
```

or

```
agent instanceof Person
```

You can put an selectOutput block to check this and send the agent to an intermediate point near the lift so it takes it, but if the AGV is a transporter that is acting as a resource, then you need to have the transporter as a variable in your agent so you can use as your condition

```
agent.transporter instanceof AGV
```

Comment: Thankyou, so the idea behind this is that you sent the transporter just as close as possible to the lift it should (with the selectoutput block) take and then it should always take the closest lift.

Comment: it takes the shortest route to the destination, you can't add lifts to your route decisions, so you need to be sure you are doing things right... if you go near the lift and then the new destination ends up being shorter using the other lift, it will take the other lift anyways... 
you might need extra logic if your lift is full at that point... but you should play around with this first I think